# How I get only the new data added to a file being watched with inotify?

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I'm using inotify to get to know when the contents of the file is changed. Now I'd like to get only the  contents of the change but I don't know how to get the exact number of bytes that was added to the file. Is this possible with inotify? I'd like an alternative solution than just read the whole file, compare with previous file in memory and make a diff out this, to get to know the change. I'm willing to avoid that also because the file can get big over time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void watchFile(char* filePath) {
    // Create an inotify instance
    int fd = inotify_init();
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("inotify_init");
        return;
    }

    // Add the file to the watch list
    int wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, filePath, IN_MODIFY);
    if (wd == -1) {
        perror("inotify_add_watch");
        return;
    }

    // Set up a buffer to hold incoming events
    char buffer[4096];

    while (true) {
        // Wait for events
        int length = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (length == -1) {
            perror("read");
            return;
        }

        // Parse the events
        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < length) {
            struct inotify_event* event = (struct inotify_event*) &buffer[offset];
            if (event->len) {
                // Seek to the end of the file
                int file = open(filePath, O_RDONLY);
                lseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

                // Read the new data from the file
                char newData[???] = {0}; // how do i calculate this?
                read(file, &newData[0], ??);

                // Handle the new data
                printf("New data: %s\n", newData);

                close(file);
            }
            offset += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len;
        }
    }

    // Stop watching the file
    inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd);

    // Close the inotify instance
    close(fd);
}

int main() {
    watchFile("path/to/file.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

so let's say I have ./a.out (compiled program of below source code) so something is written to path/to/file.txt like `baa`, later `foo`, `hehe` and so on. the expect output of below program is:

```
New data: baa
New data: foo
New data: hehe
```

Comment: Probably don't want inotify at all. Open the file for reading, seek to the end, try to read. If the file isn't opened in non-blocking mode that'll pause until there's newly written data past the old end available to read.

Comment: Or are you interested in the writer overwriting existing bits of the file instead of just appending?

Comment: @Shawn you're right! I don't need need inotify at all not even lseek() call. didn't came across my mind at time to `read` like that.

Comment: @Shawn no i didnt need to overwriting anything. just read the last data (lines) appened by other application (a video stream that ocally write data to a csv file output)